# install multiple apps by one entry in INSTALLED_APPS in django (dependency)

Tags: django, django-apps

is the concept of dependencies available in Django apps too?

For example, let's say I'm building my own custom Django app "`polls`" that can be reused in any Django project.

so whenever you need to add it to a project, you will have to add

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
]
```

but let's also say, that this polls app depends on the Django REST Framework, so whenever you use it, you will have to add that as well

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

And how about if it depends on even way more apps, do I have to list them all again in the `settings.py` of each and every project?

Or, is there some way to add `rest_framework` as an installed app inside the `apps.py` of the `polls` app so that it's automatically installed whenever polls is installed on a project?

Answer (score 1):

The *pluggable* apps cant override the host project's settings. We can add more [checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/checks/)  and validations to the apps before the project run.

---

FYI: to validate the presence of the dependency package, we can make use of the [***`ready(...)`***--(DOC)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method of **`PollsConfig`** class as,

```py
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig


class PollsConfig(AdminConfig):

    def ready(self):
        try:
            import rest_framework
        except ImportError:
            raise ValueError("Missing 'rest_framework' from 'INSTALLED_APPS'")
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of doing that as the last option. But why can't it work just like in any package manager? I don't expect it to override settings.py. I'm just expecting a more abstract hierarchical structure. Like when you install a PyPi package, and it depends on some other packages, it automatically checks which of these packages are missing and automatically install them

Comment: of course, this can be a nice feature (at the first sight) and wish to see it on the Django mainstream. Maybe, any of us didn't think of this feature yet. But, it is not too late to add a feature suggestion to the Django community and we can see whats the thought of the core members on this particular feature is.